# How Can I Display Users Posts also whether it is logged in or logged out

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I want to display user's posts and profile data in profile page post by specific user whether it is logged in or logged out. When I click the any user it will show me users profile info but I want user's posts and profile info. How can I solve this?

Here is my code

posts/views.py

```
class AllPosts(ListView):
    model = Post
    paginate_by = 3
    template_name = 'posts/post_list.html'
    def get(self, request):
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created')
        users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
        args = {
            'posts': posts, 'users': users
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

account/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
​
​
def view_profile(request, pk=None):
    if pk:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    else:
        user = request.user
    args = {'user': user}
    return render(request, 'posts/profile.html', args)
​
```

account/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
app_name = "account"
​
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^profile/$', views.view_profile, name='view_profile'),
    url(r'^profile/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.view_profile, name='view_profile_with_pk'),
]
​
# account/models.py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    website = models.URLField(default='')
    phone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)
​
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

I want this page to show all posts contents posted by user whether they are logged in or logged out 
Thank You in Advance

Comment: I don't see your posts view, where you have tried to show all posts

Comment: https://dpaste.de/YZ4r

Comment: so now, what's the issue? what have you tried and get stuck?